# Jquery Time Error

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a web Service in C# returning me time objects.

While reading the object in jquery, for some reason I get very wierd values.

Web Service return values:

```
endTIme: 11:00:00
startTIme: 10:00:00
```

While reading in Jquery, I get 
**PT10H-PT11H** instead of 10:00 am- 11:00 am

My Code:

```
dropDownList.append("<option value='" + test.Id + "'>" + test.startTime + "-" + test.endTime + "(" + test.vaccancies + ")" + "</option>");
```

Here is my code

**Object Class**

```
public class MyResponse       
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public List<MySlots> Slots { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MySlots : ResponseBase
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int slotId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public TimeSpan startTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public TimeSpan endTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Sql Parameter**

```
DateTime dtStartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(newstartTime, "HHmm",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

dtST = dtStartTime.ToString("HH:mm tt");

dtET = dtStartTime.AddMinutes(60).ToString("HH:mm tt");

db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@startTime", DbType.Time, (dtST));

db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@endTime", DbType.Time, (dtET));
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is not an error. The format is ISO8601 format. Show your C# code.

Comment: Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it better with https://momentjs.com/. Try parsing it while getting the response from web service. It should be super easy like

`moment('11:00:00').format('HH:mm ss');`

Comment: That's just how .net serializes the TimeSpan properties. Either look into changing the serialization or parse that string client-side to get to your desired output.